# deserialising does not work

Tags: c#, xml

This is the xml stream:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<historydetails>
    <taskEvent>
        <eventtype>Transitions</eventtype> 
        <historyevent>Task moved</historyevent> 
        <details>From 'Requested' to 'In Validation'</details> 
        <author>NAme</author> 
        <entrydate>01 Jul 13, 11:34</entrydate> 
       <historyid>2620</historyid> 
    </taskEvent>
    <taskEvent>
      <eventtype>Updates</eventtype> 
      <historyevent>Subtask marked done</historyevent> 
      <details>Subtask: visualise status and versions</details> 
      <author>NAme2</author> 
      <entrydate>21 Jun 13, 10:16</entrydate> 
     <historyid>2588</historyid> 
    </taskEvent>
</historydetails>
```

The corresponding classes look like this:

```
public class historydetails
{
    [XmlElement("taskEvent")]
    List<taskEvent> eventList = new List<taskEvent>();
}

public class taskEvent
{
    string eventtype { get; set; }
    string historyevent { get; set; }
    string details { get; set; }
    string author { get; set; }
    string entrydate { get; set; }
    string historyid { get; set; }
}
```

the code to deserialise the xml (the string replacement contains the xml code):

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(historydetails));                              
object obj = obj = deserializer.Deserialize(stringToStream(replacement));           
historydetails XmlData = (historydetails)obj;
```

The method stringToStream

```
private MemoryStream stringToStream(string input)
{
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
    return stream;
}
```

The result that i get is as following:
The object XmlData is made and there is a list of taskEvents.
The problem is in the list itself: it is empty...

Comment: Have you tried populating the object yourself and serializing it to XML to compare against?  If it's an issue with the hierarchy of your elements, you'll notice immediately.

Comment: Questions where "it doesn't work" are almost unanswerable unless you `try{/*fail*/}catch(Exception ex){ ex.ToString(); }` and add the result of `ToString` to your question.

Comment: Will, he isn't getting an error.  He is getting a valid XML object but it is empty.

Comment: i tried populating it myself, and there was the error, offcourse very stupid one= there was no public in the describing of the propertys in the classes. thank you very much

Comment: You're also leaking a `MemoryStream` in your code that deserialises the XML. use `using (var stream = stringToStream(replacement)) { object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(stream); historydetails XmlData = (historyDetails)obj; }`

Comment: Also, your XML document says it's in UTF-8, but you're using `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()`. Use `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes()` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to make the members public

```
public class historydetails
{
    [XmlElement("taskEvent")]
    public List<taskEvent> eventList = new List<taskEvent>();
}

  public class taskEvent
{
    public string eventtype { get; set; }
    public string historyevent { get; set; }
    public string details { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public string entrydate { get; set; }
    public string historyid { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As an aside, for future reference (with Visual Studio 2012 or the WebEssentials plugin), one of the easiest way to create the classes based on some sample XML content data is to copy it into the clipboard and then use the built-in VS function: *EDIT - > Paste Special -> Paste XML As Classes* into a new class file.

- It leaves less space for errors like the one you encountered and
- It's fast, you'll have your classes ready in a few seconds

Comment: does this use the XSD generator tool?

Comment: Good question, I'm not sure at the moment. I've been looking around in the IL for the implementation, but I gave up. It would be interesting to know how it's done.